# JGit throws MissingObjectException and says missing unknown commit ID

Tags: jgit

I'm using JGit to extract diffs between two commits but I often face a problem that JGit throws `MissingObjectException` and says missing unknown commit ID like this:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing unknown 9eae334e9492f55a841e6eb7ab302ff11d03ab21
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectReader.open(ObjectReader.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.parseAny(RevWalk.java:890)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.parseCommit(RevWalk.java:800)
    at collect.CollectTestcase.autoExtraction(CollectTestcase.java:99)*
```

It often happens when running the code

```java
RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repo);
walk.parseCommit(commitId)
```

Does someone knows what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

JGit throws a `MissingObjectException` if there is no object with the given ID in the repository.

There are different types of objects in git, common are commits, blobs, and trees.

`RevWalk` offers API to search for specific types, like `parseCommit`, as well as for any type of object with `parseAny`. The information, that you were searching for a commit, gets lost along the way which leads to the confusing 'unknown' in the error message. It should actually read 'Missing commit abc...'.

But despite the irritating message, it means that there is no such commit. Either you are passing the ID of an object of a different type, e.g. a tree object, or there is no such object at all. You can use `parseAny` to see if there is an object with the given ID. If an object could be found, use `getType` of the returned `RevObject` to find out which type it is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have checked the scenario of the Exception.
It happens in tomcat85, the original repo cannot be found in GitHub.
I pulled from a mirror in https://github.com/lelou6666/tomcat85
However, when I try to parse the commit of `9601a937ff3b7ef5d04b2a0e950d0e44e1bb4cbd`, it happens.
Even though I can visit this commit, it says "This commit doesn't belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository"
I also tried `git checkout` and it says 'reference is not a tree'
Maybe it's caused by the mirror repo? How can I parse such a commit?